# Disable bean validation in case of clearing/resetting form

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

CASE: the form contains input text for entering department name (can't be null or blank), and drop down list for selecting parent department (can be null), when entering data, and pressing clear, the clear method in backing bean works fine as expected, but when not entering data and pressing clear, the bean validation for not blank on the name works and validation message appears, and i want to disable the validation in case of clearing.

1. **View Code**:

   Department Name:

   ```
   <h:outputLabel>Parent Department:</h:outputLabel>
       <ice:selectOneMenu id="parentDepartment" value="#{department.selectedParentDepartment}">               
         <f:selectItem/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{departmentBean.departmentList}" var="dept" 
          itemLabel="#{dept.name}" itemValue="#{dept.id}" />                            
       </ice:selectOneMenu> 
       <h:message for="parentDepartment" style="color:red" />        

   <ice:panelGroup>
       <h:commandLink value="Add New" action="#{departmentBean.addOrUpdateDepartment}" />
       <h:commandLink value="Add New" actionListener="#{departmentBean.clear}" />
   </ice:panelGroup>
   ```
2. **Bean Validation**:

   `@NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
   @Size(max = 25, message = "{long.value}")
   @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
   private String name;`
3. **Backing Bean Method**:

   `public void clear() {
           setDepartmentObj(new Department());
           setSelectedParentDepartment(0);
       }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let it refresh the entire view instead:

```
<h:commandLink value="Clear" action="#{bean.clear}" immediate="true" />
```

with

```
public String clear() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The `immediate="true"` will skip processing (and validation) of all input components which doesn't have `immediate="true"`.

Alternatively, a piece of JavaScript to reload the page should also do:

```
<h:commandLink value="Clear" onclick="window.location.reload(); return false;" />
```

---

**Update** as per the comments you want a partial request, then just use ajax:

```
<h:commandLink value="Clear" action="#{bean.clear}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```

with

```
public void clear() {
    field1 = null;
    field2 = null;
    // ...
}
```

Because the `execute` is set to `@this` (which is already the default value by the way, so you can omit it), it won't process the entire form.

Comment: what if that i don't want to reload the whole page, since i forgot to mention that the page contains some tree components, and by reloading the whole page, they will be reloaded too, which doesn't make sense when clearing the form,i just want to reload the form only, you get my idea ?

Comment: there's still one case, when trying to clear after the validation of empty name occurs, it doesn't clear the form, although it enters the clear method.

Answer (score 0):

Some components have a `valueChangeListener`. Try to work with that one. However I'm not sure if that will trigger the validation as well.